# CKEditor not correctly apply span tags

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, rich-text-editor, ckeditor4.x

I use CKEditor 4 and have this problem:

**This occurs when the web page opened and editor field is empty.**

We simply enter the text without any changes in style(font and etc), but default font and size does not applying. So result will be

> `<html>some text</html>`

instead of something like this

> `<html><span style="font-family: courier; font-size: 10pt">some text</span></html>`

If the ckeditor opened with some ready text in it everything is ok.
How can we make that when ckeditor field is empty the default fonts will be applied automatically?

Answer (score 0):

`innerhtml` will remove the styles.

Change like for ex. `<div id="changehere" [innerHTML]="changehere"></div>`

Comment: but I need to apply default style not remove